# Send page content to email

Tags: php, email

I want to send the page content to an email. 
I wrote

```
if($_GET['send_mail'] == 1){
$message = file_get_contents('send_daily_bespoke_call_status.php');
echo "sendmail" . $message;
mail('abc@gmail.com', 'Report for Bespoke Users', $message);    
}
```

but then page is not taking forever to load.
How can I send the page contents to an email.
My page contents has several arrays, so I can't include << etc.

Comment: you need to specify the right smtp server in php.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using object buffering:

```
if($_GET['send_mail'] == 1){
    ob_start();
    include 'send_daily_bespoke_call_status.php';
    $output_buffer = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    mail('abc@gmail.com', 'Report for Bespoke Users', $output_buffer);
}
```

Also, instead of `mail()` you could use PEAR's SMTP Mail package: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/

Comment: This is worked for me.

$body = file_get_contents('send_daily_bespoke_call_status.php');

$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

mail('abc@gmail.com', 'Report for Bespoke Users', $body);